# np.c_ throwing a valueerror for the correct size of arrays

Tags: python, numpy

I’m facing an issue with array concatenation. Array details are below.

First array from columntransformer
(1168,286) (scipy.sparse._csr.csr_matrix)

Second array from numpy array
(1168,)

It would be great to see the solution for concatenation of two arrays.

Thanks!

Comment: Please provide a reproductible example, as well as things you have tried so far.

Comment: Here's Github link of python script where I am getting an error. 

https://github.com/may-py/ML-ADV-House-Price-Prediction/blob/main/src/components/data_transformaion.py

Comment: all examples in stackoverflow require to be complete inside stackoverflow. Try to simplify the problem to only the strict part that is creating the error, so people can look into it

Comment: Also, could you post the complete traceback of the error, please?

Comment: Traceback (most recent call last):
data_ingestion.py", line 50, in <module>

data_transformaion.py", line 113, in initiate_data_transformation

data_transformaion.py", line 94, in initiate_data_transformation

env\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\index_tricks.py", line 419, in __getitem__
    res = self.concatenate(tuple(objs), axis=axis)
  File "<__array_function__ internals>", line 200, in concatenate
ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 1 and the array at index 1 has size 1168

Comment: The same error found in notebook line no 8.

https://github.com/may-py/ML-ADV-House-Price-Prediction/blob/main/notebook/notebook/eda.ipynb

Comment: `np.c_` requires dense arrays.  For sparse use `sparse.hstack`.  The second may need to be sparse as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For test purpose I created smaller arrays (5 rows, 3 columns):

```
import scipy.sparse as ss
r = 5; c = 3
a1 = ss.csr_matrix((data, (row_ind, col_ind)), shape=(r, c))
a2 = np.arange(21, r + 21)
```

Note that *np.c_* is able to cope with "normal" (dense) arrays, but fails when you pass it a **sparse** array.

So when you attempt to run e.g.: `np.c_[a1, a2]` you will get a *ValueError*.

The solution here is to convert the first array (*a1*) to a **dense** one.

Then, when you run e.g. `np.c_[a1.todense(), a2]` you will get:

```
matrix([[10,  0,  0, 21],
        [ 0,  0, 20, 22],
        [ 0,  0,  0, 23],
        [ 0, 30,  0, 24],
        [40,  0, 50, 25]])
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. It did work. 
I have done the same in another project and it is not raising error.

Comment: @Mayur If this solves your problem then you should accept the answer by clicking the check next to it.

Comment: I have reached to another error while model training. 

TypeError: np.matrix is not supported. Please convert to a numpy array with np.asarray. For more information see: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html

Comment: Just do what has been written in the error message: convert your source array to a numpy array with _np.asarray_.

Comment: Get it done with two array. "scipy.sparse.csr_matrix.toarray"

Instead of .todense(), I use .toarray() and reached the end of the project.